# Node.js Socket.IO client 'unhandled socket.io url'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm attempting to have a node.js client communicate with a node.js server using Socket.IO, according to the documentation this should be pretty easy however I'm just getting a message 'info  - unhandled socket.io url' on the server whenever the clients tries to connect to the server. Here is a very basic example from the root:

---

in a directory I installed the necessary Socket.IO modules using:

```
npm install socket.io socket.io-client
```

in a file servernode.js I put:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(), io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('connected');
});
app.listen(60000);
```

in another file clientnode.js I put:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:60000');
socket.on('connect', function(){
     console.log('socket connected.');
});
```

in two terminals I put

```
node servernode.js
```

and

```
node clientnode.js
```

Then in the server I get this message repeated ad infinitum:

```
 info - unhandled socket.io url
```

---

I've searched for this message and from what I could gather, it was related to differences between versions, but I suppose npm has those modules synched, no? In desperation I also tried getting the file from the server module at './node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js' (and using .connect - somehow in this version it's necessary) but then I get another error:

```
/home/work/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js:1877
var port = global.location.port ||
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'port' of undefined
at Socket.isXDomain (/home/work/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js:1877:31)
at Socket.handshake (/home/work/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js:1627:14)
at Socket.connect (/home/work/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js:1699:10)
at new Socket (/home/work/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js:1551:12)
at Object.io.connect (/home/work/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js:94:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/work/testnode2.js:1:160)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try using a newer version of socket.io, it worked for me.

```
npm install socket.io@1.0
```

Comment: Yup, it worked for me too. I wasn't aware 1.0 was available already and I didn't even know you could pick module versions in npm like that. It's so handy! :D Thanks for the help!

Comment: Has anybody solution for 0.9.* version?

Comment: @the.ufon It worked for 0.9 in a similar way:
`npm install socket.io@0.9 socket.io-client@0.9`